# How to migrate from jquery fullcalendar 1.6.1 to latest version

Tags: fullcalendar

Can you provide the step of migration.
I had use jquery fullcalendar 1.6.1 which is not support event slot overlap but i want to prevent event overlaping.

Comment: delete all fullcalendar 1.6.1 files; install fullcalendar 2.3.0; done.

Comment: @northkildonan will it affect older functionality? as in my application, it is already used fullcalendar functions.